# Unable to validate count of an SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to validate count of a table, but the query continuously running for 20 mins.
What could be wrong?

```
IF((select COUNT(1) from test.[dbo].[as_EmployeeData] (nolock) ed
JOIN test.[dbo].DepartmentData dd ON ed.EmployeeId= dd.DepartmentData
AND dd.Name = 'IT' AND dd.Status = 'Completed')= 0
)
BEGIN
PRINT 'Successful'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'Failed'
END
```

Whereas if I run the below query I get the result as 0

```
select COUNT(1) from test.[dbo].[as_EmployeeData] (nolock) ed
JOIN test.[dbo].DepartmentData dd ON ed.EmployeeId= dd.DepartmentData
AND dd.Name = 'IT' AND dd.Status= 'Completed'
```

Comment: I suspect we are missing something here.

Comment: You don't need to (nor should you) count to know if any rows exist. That can be very inefficient. Use EXISTS. And stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: You have an "I don't care about accuracy" hint on one table, but not the other. Did you check for blocking? Do you have adequate indexes that make the join efficient? Anyway - [Bad Habits - Counting Rows the Hard Way](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way)

Comment: I tried this but still taking same time:
`IF NOT EXISTS(select 1 from test.[dbo].[as_EmployeeData] (nolock) ed
JOIN test.[dbo].DepartmentData dd ON ed.EmployeeId= dd.DepartmentData
AND dd.Name = 'IT' AND dd.Status = 'Completed'
)
BEGIN
PRINT 'Successful'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'Failed'
END`
@SMor

Comment: Perhaps if we knew WHY you're trying to do this, then we might be able to point you in the right direction a bit better...

Comment: I want to validate if there are any rows available in the `as_EmployeeData`, if the count is 0 it means successful else means false @AndrewCorrigan

Comment: @the_coder_guy That is not "why", that is "how". And you are looking for rows that satisfy the join - don't oversimplify your goal or logic. If the query hangs using the NOLOCK for both tables, then there is something you are not telling us or seeing yourself. And if you are going to use hints, then use current (not DEPRECATED) syntax as suggested in answer. You will need to figure out WHY the query is hanging (i.e., "blocked").

Answer (score -1):

One option is to stick it in a variable:

```
DECLARE @myCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                        FROM test.[dbo].[as_EmployeeData] ed
                             INNER JOIN test.[dbo].DepartmentData dd 
                                        ON dd.DepartmentData = ed.EmployeeId 
                                           AND dd.Name = 'IT' 
                                           AND dd.Status= 'Completed');

IF @myCount != 0
BEGIN 
    PRINT 'Successful'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Failed'
END
```

However, the `COUNT` will gradually become more and more inefficient as more and more data is entered.

Your best bet is to do an `EXISTS` check:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
           FROM test.[dbo].[as_EmployeeData] ed
                INNER JOIN test.[dbo].DepartmentData dd 
                           ON dd.DepartmentData = ed.EmployeeId 
                              AND dd.Name = 'IT' 
                              AND dd.Status= 'Completed')
BEGIN
     PRINT 'Successful'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
     PRINT 'Failed'
END
```

That said - I can't see the logical reason for such a query; what else are you doing in the if/else block?

Answer (score -1):

you could try to do a `top 1` in stead of a count, and then use an exists

```
IF ( exists( select top 1 1
             from test.[dbo].[as_EmployeeData] ed
               JOIN test.[dbo].DepartmentData dd 
                 ON ed.EmployeeId = dd.DepartmentData
                AND dd.Name = 'IT' 
                AND dd.Status = 'Completed'
           )
   )
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Successful'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Failed'
END
```

Answer (score -2):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
            FROM test.[dbo].[as_EmployeeData] AS ED WITH(NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN test.[dbo].DepartmentData AS DD WITH(NOLOCK) ON ED.EmployeeId = DD.DepartmentData
            WHERE DD.[Name] = 'IT' AND DD.[Status] = 'Completed')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Successful'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Failed'
END
```

Comment: I tried the same, still the query keeps executing